# Understanding the proof of Corollary 6 on page 76 in Royden "Fourth Edition".

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation

The corollary and part of its proof are given below:

> [image]

But I do not understand why the last statement is true, could anyone explains this for me please?

Comment: if $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, then $\chi_{A\cup B}=\chi_{A}+\chi_{B}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, one has $\chi_{A\cup B}=\chi_A+\chi_B$. This follows easily from the *definition* of the indicator function $\chi$. For any set $S$, 
$$
\chi_S(x)=\begin{cases}
0&\text{if }x\not\in S\\
1&\text{if }x\in S
\end{cases}.
$$

Now, $\chi_{A\cup B}=\chi_A+\chi_B$ is the same as $\chi_{A\cup B}(x)=\chi_A(x)+\chi_B(x)$ for every $x$. There are only three cases to check and I will leave them to you:

- $x\in A$;
- $x\in B$;
- $x\not\in A\cup B$.

Answer (score 2):

By definition, if 
$\chi_{A}(x) =1 $ if $ x\in A  $ and $\chi_{A}(x) =0 $ otherwise

As A and B are disjoint, we must have  $\chi_{A \cup B} =\chi_{A}+\chi_{  B} $, implying
 $f \times \chi_{A \cup B} =f \times (\chi_{A}+\chi_{  B}) =f \times \chi_{A}+ f \times \chi_{  B}$

Comment: My question is exactly why "As A and B are disjoint, we must have  $\chi_{A \cup B} =\chi_{A}+\chi_{  B} $"? could you elaborate this please?